# Switch between TWO different WAN providers on schedule

Tags: networking, router, lan, pfsense

I have two internet providers at home, the one offers an uncapped service from 23H00 to 18H00 the following day, and the other provider is an LTE provider to use between 18H00 to 23H00 daily

I'm planning on the following scenario:

Use **provider_1** daily from 18H00 to 23H00, From there at 23H00 switch over **provider_2** automatically until 18H00 the following day, etc.

My thoughts were to connect both routers on the LAN with static IP's ie. 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.1.2/24, then install something like pfSence on a Raspberry PI and assign IP address 192.168.1.3/24 and make that my gateway.

I would disable DHCP on both WAN routers and let pfSence take care of that.

Would pfSence be able to automatically switch between **provider_1** and **provider_2** on a schedule? and would it work on a Raspberry Pi with only 1 LAN interface?

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You do not need in pfSence to solve this task. It's enough to create 2 simple scripts which rewrites your default gateway (`route delete 0.0.0.0 && route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.X`), and execute them from task scheduler.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, but I have many devices hanging off that internal network, ie. game consoles, smart TV's, etc.

Comment: If so install some router in your network between routers and another nodes, and shedule this task on it. Or think about to buy some double-WAN router.

Comment: Pfsense is the easiest way to do this. Make a gateway group once you have pf configured for both isps. Then add the time schedule through the firewall rules, and done

Comment: @Tim_Stewart thanks so much, I have made a VM with 3 (1 internal and 2 wan) NIC's and done as you suggested, Works like a charm!

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I'm busy testing another solution with a Mikrotik Routerboard If it works Ill document both here as an answer